# how to validate large amount of unlabeled data by using small amount of labeled data?

Tags: classification, predictive-models, prediction

I have  to predict  large amount of unlabeled data with the help of  small amount of labeled data by using classification model.
How can I validate that this prediction is true or not ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. How can you check the truth of something when you have no information about whether it is true?